# ng-class style does not apply

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm updating the color of the text inside a div tag based on a value of an array inside a ng-repeat. that value is correctly set when I debug but the color does not set properly.

```
<div ng-class="sel.fav == 'Y' ? 'fz-horse-name-green' : 'fz-horse-name'">{{sel.sel_name}} : {{sel.fav}}</div>
```

and my css class is:

```
.fz-horse-name-green{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 220%;
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    color: limegreen !important;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
.fz-horse-name{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 220%;
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
```

and the value I checked inside the class is

> sel.fav prints "Y" correctly inside the same div but the css color does not appear even I added "!important".

when I look at the HTML snippet in chrome developer mode, it shows as below:

```
<div ng-class="sel.fav == 'Y' ? 'fz-horse-name-green' : 'fz-horse-name'" class="ng-binding fz-horse-name-green">TOYNEBEE : Y</div>
```

that means the correct class is already applied right? what could be the issue not applying my css / not changing the color of the text correctly based on the condition?

I have created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfbv3jvu/1/) and it works fine. Wonder why the actual is not working?

http://plnkr.co/edit/XhaxncmzzNFXmZryKkyr?p=preview

Comment: on quick look your code seems fine, so there must be problem somewhere else. Its always good to make a working fiddle

Comment: You can use developer tools and inspect `your` div and find out what else affects on its color.

Comment: Please create demo that replicates problem

Comment: I have submitted an edit (add http://plnkr.co/edit/XhaxncmzzNFXmZryKkyr?p=preview as plnkr) ... this plunkr works tho... so the problem is not the code you showed.

Comment: This might be a dumb comment, but are you sure that the css-file is loaded properly, it could be that you have done your update but the browser still uses a cached version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item should always have `fz-horse-name` class

```
.fz-horse-name{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 220%;
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
```

The `fav` class should just modify the existing class

```
.fz-horse-name.fav{
    color: limegreen;
}
```

Then you can add the `fav` class if the condition is true

```
<div class="fz-horse-name" ng-class="{'fav': (sel.fav == 'Y')}">
  {{sel.sel_name}} : {{sel.fav}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer, but merely a suggestion to use other stylings / formattings.

Comment: not sure what was wrong in my code, but this works fine. thanks Vinko